# Apache Camel - Deploy war application with RouteBuilder

Tags: apache-camel

Im new to Apache Camel, Please let me know How do we deploy a war with camel which activate routeBulder automatically?

I have configure in the applicationContext.xml

```
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="camel-3">
<routeBuilder ref="SearchProcessRoute" />
```

```
<bean id="SearchProcessRoute" class="camel.core.SearchProcessRouteBuilder" />
```

and the Route builder

```
public class SearchProcessRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    from("activemq://search.queue")
    .log("Process from the queue")
    .bean("SearchProcessBean","ProcessData")
    .to("activemq://search.process.queue");
}}
```

When I send a message to the search.queue it doesnt process anything?

Please let me know the proper way to deploy a web app with camel (Is there any sample application) and how do we solve the above issue?

PS. I was able to execute this as a standalone application. However, What I want to achieve is that connect from the standalone application to the activmq ("activemq://search.queue") which is deployed in the war and then the route (SearchProcessRouteBuilder) which is in the war activate automatically and that would process the queue. Then it will send the message to the other queue "activemq://search.process.queue".

Is this possible with Apache Camel, if So how we can achieve this?

Comment: i think jetty server listens for http requests only, so on top of your active mq queue you will have to write a http layer code also meaning servlets or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to add the following to the web.xml to bootstrap the Spring/Camel contexts

```
<!-- location of spring xml files -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- the listener that kick-starts Spring -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

see http://camel.apache.org/servlet-tomcat-example.html

Comment: When I did bit more research on this found out that you could do the same without spring. See http://camel.apache.org/servlet-tomcat-no-spring-example.html. Available as of Camel 2.11

Comment: Hi boday, Please let me know how to handle below scenario. I send the Pojo Object to the Queue which is in the war and then withing the war I need to read from the Queue and process the Object. Once that is done that Object set to another Queue (Processed Queue). What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Comment: if you just need to send data in between queues and processors, then the cleanest way is to define a dedicated route per queue and just send data in between routes/queues...not sure what you are asking otherwise